# How to find the probability of selecting two numbers from 1 to 8 with no common prime factor?

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me this problem? The following is my understanding. The set of the integers is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 2, 3, 5, 7 are not common prime factor. My answer is not right.

> Two different integers are randomly selected from the set of integers greater than 0 and less than 9. What is the probability that they have not common prime factor? Express your answer as a common fraction.

Comment: What's your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
1,2,3,2^2,5,2\cdot3,7,2^3
$$
There are $\binom{8}{2}$ possible pairs. Any pair of numbers in $\{2,2^2,2\cdot3,2^3\}$ is with a common prime factor. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ such pairs. To those pairs we need to add the pair $3$, $2\cdot3$. Clearly there are no other pair with a common prime factor.

Thus the probability sought is
$$
1-\frac{\binom{4}{2}+1}{\binom{8}{2}} = \frac{3}{4}
$$

Comment: "Sought" rather than "seeked."

Comment: @symplectomorphic Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- $3$ and $6$ have common prime factors, you do not want to select both of those.
- $2$, $4$, $6$, $8$ all have a common prime factor, you do not want your selection to be any pair of those.
- (NB: if this selection *allows* repetition, you also do not wish to select the same number twice)

Answer (score 1):

You can use complementary counting. First find the pairs where the integers would have a common prime factor. The pairs are $(2,4)\;(2,6)\;(2,8)\;(3,6)\;(4,6)\;(4,8)\;(6,8)$. The total number of ways to choose two different integers from the set would be $\dfrac{8\times 7}2=28$ ways. So then $$1-\dfrac7{28}=\dfrac{21}{28}=\dfrac34$$